# Outlook integration error in communicator

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010, office-communicator-2007

I am using office communicator 2007. I have configured my outlook with two exchange servers(one for my office server another is client server). communicator will take my office credentials. But it is giving an yellow colored warning like "Outlook integration error". It is not integrated with outlook server. my communicator messages are not saving in outlook. how to solve this error?